# How to use tornadoredis connection_pool

Tags: tornado, connection-pooling, tornado-redis

I declare connection_pool in main.py before web service running

```
    CONNECTION_POOL = tornadoredis.ConnectionPool(
        max_connections=10, wait_for_available=True)

    client = tornadoredis.Client(
        connection_pool=CONNECTION_POOL
    )
    client.connect()
    client.subscribe("user", lambda msg: client.listen(WSHandler.on_messages_published))
```

When i do the stress test, i find out that the truely connection number is over 200, but i have already set `max_connections=10`.

So i don't know why it happened.

Comment: What version of `tornado-redis`? How did you test? How did you count those 200 connections - on redis, on client; netstat, logs?

Comment: I use latest `tornado-redis`  and i write a simple python script to simulate the Production Environment,  i count connection number on redis server and local netstat